# Artificial intelligence simulating mathematicians (what a distopia!)

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, proof-theory, machine-learning, proof-assistants

This is kind of soft and naive question, so feel free to shame on me :)

I start from the fact that, in my opinion, what humans are interested in about mathematics are things that we find deep and yet simple - somehow, that we find beautiful or enlightening. There are for sure out there useful concepts that takes 10 000 pages to be defined and theorems that requires 100 years to be read, but fortunately we will never get them. We are smarter!

So now let's take a logical system like ZFC. This yields a graph with well formed and provable sentences as vertices and simple deductions as edges (I mean deductions that are obtained by applying just one inference rule). Let me set some basic concepts:

--A *deduction* $a$ is a path on this graph, also denoted as $v \to\to w$ (starting and ending point).

-- We say that $w$ is provable from $v$ if there exist a deduction $v \to \to w$.

-- Also, we say that $w$ is provable from $v$ through $x \to \to y$, if there exist deductions $v \to \to x \to \to y \to \to w$.

-- If $a:=x \to \to y$,  and $w$ is provable from $v$ through $a$, set $\ell_a(v,w)$ the length of the shortest path from $v$ to $w$ factoring through $a$, minus the length of the deduction a.

-- As well $\ell_0(v,w)$ is the length of the shortest path from $v$ to $w$.

-- A deduction $a$ is said to be $\gamma$-useful, if for every $w$ provable from $v$ through $a$, $\ell_a(v,w) \le \gamma \ell_0(v,w)$.

Now everybody would agree that an AI which is able to discover 3-or-so-useful deductions would be great. I'd like to have mine if someone invented it. Basically it output theorems that appears in short proofs.

My first question is so purely mathematical:

1. Can the definition be a bit weakened to say that what I said holds "on average" or most of the times? How this could be formalized? Also, maybe it's good to relativize this concept to "areas". It's very unlikely for us that a big theorem in measure theory is applied many times in category theory. Maybe this is already cut down by limiting to proofs that factors through our theorem.
2. Does this definition really make sense? For example, set for a deduction $a$ 
   $$\gamma(a) = \sup \{ \frac{\ell_a(v,w)}{\ell_0(v,w)} : w \text{ is provable from } v \text{ through } a \} $$
   Is this number really giving some information? I am not even sure it's not constant. It would be great if you could compute it for a class of deductions in a toy model logical system, to see if it captures the idea of usefulness we have.

An idea for point one to get a natural filtration in finite graphs  would be to show that the graphs $G_x = \{ y:  x \text{ is provable from } y\}$ have a finite number of equivalence classes. A part of this statement is saying that there cannot be arbitrarily long deductions from axioms to a given statement, where implications are strict. 
This seems true to me under mild assumptions on the system.

Now let's get to second question. Say also that my definitions above are not the best. Beside this, mathematicians are great in finding useful stuff, or to invent concepts that appears over and over in a lot of proofs (given the specialization of the subject). Intuitively,  the bad thing about inventing an AI for proofs is that it does not have a "local" reward system; it's not clear (even for us) if some deductions will eventually get to a solution, and the number of trial-and-errors is exponential in the length as we have an homogeneous degree given by the number of inference rules.

In some chess machines, this is overcome by training machines at the beginning to play with human opponents. Later on, they let different instances of the same AI playing between them. Here come my second question:

Has a statistical learning machine that "learns from mathematicians" (so they become the "local reward system") ever been tried? Like someone that stays there and says "bad idea"/"good idea", and when the machine is a bit trained you let them say bad/good among them in a kind of AI-mathematicians-coomunity.

I think that most of us has experienced exposing an idea to a professor which misteriously says "could work" or "could not", when even himself didn't know precisely why. But then most of the times he was right! XD

Hope to have answers from both AI and logic experts. Both technical and "soft" answers are welcome!

Comment: The graph model is inadequate: modus ponens takes two arguments.

Comment: Ok, so maybe is better to have an operadic model? i.e. a bunch of operations (= inferences) subjected to some constraints?

Comment: However, I don't think it is necessary to think it as two variable thing. Modus ponens is $\phi(A,B,C ) \Rightarrow \psi(A,C)$, and it is a way to pass from a single sentence to another single sentence. Here $\phi(x,y,z) = (x \Rightarrow y) \land (y \Rightarrow z)$ while $\psi(x,z) = x \Rightarrow z$.

Comment: The graph is not locally finite. The elimination of a universal quantifier can be applied to any term, so it will have infinitely many successors. If you're going to talk about statistics, you'll need some measures or distributions.

Comment: But more importantly, I don't see any evidence whatsoever that your graph has anything to do with how mathematical knowledge is actually structured.

Comment: I don't know, I am in representation theory (so neither logic nor AI), but it seems to me that when I learn a theorem is a way to conceptualize a lot of steps in one. When I use theorem I then refer to that idea. Shortly seems like we mathematicians use just some paths=theorems and the resulting length is computed by how many paths we have used. What do you see missing here?

Comment: @andrej Bauer: also, I don't see why your argument yields non local finiteness. Unless I am misunderstanding, to eliminate a universal quantifier you need one in your sentence, so it can't be applied to any term. Even if you have an inference rule that you can apply to any sentence and you have $x \to Fx \to F^2x \to ... $ it is not evident to me that exist a y such that  $F^nx $ implies y for every $n$. This holds in case by locally finite you mean that the freely generated category is not locally finite.

Comment: The theorem $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . n + 1 = 1 + n$ has infinitely many successors by elimination of $\forall$ (i.e., plug in a value for $n$), namely $0 + 1 = 1 + 0$, $0 + 2 = 2 + 0$, $0 + 3 = 3 + 0$, etc.

Comment: Well, I understood that automatic proof is harder than I thought. I found a thesis from JP Bridge in Cambridge "Machine learning and automated theorem proving" that probably address my curiosity in a more general and well established framework. Thanks for the clues!